# ICommand is going to the itemsource instead of the datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I know my command as is, is not finding the right path.

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'OnButtonClickedCommand' property not found on 'App1.Helper.FoodTypes, App1.Windows, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='OnButtonClickedCommand' DataItem='App1.Helper.FoodTypes, App1.Windows, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button' (Name='button1'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Below I use the element in the items source to setup the tag and content. However I want the Command that I sent, to be sent to the datacontext. But instead it is being sent to the same element.

**MenuItemsPage.xaml**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="foodTypeTemplate">
    <Button x:Name="button1" Width="100" Height="50" Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Name}" 
              Command="{Binding OnButtonClickedCommand}"                   
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button1}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I know that the command is going to the element of the item source (CategoryButtonList) since if I replace the **OnButtonClickedCommand** with **Name**, the path will be found. Instead I want it to be going to the datacontext that I set up in the *cs* file. From what I researched, you are supposed to use RelativeResource with FindAncestorType however it seems to not be supported on my platform.

```
Error   3   The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.
```

Reason why I want it to go to the datacontext is because that is where all the logic of is.

Below is how I have my ItemsSource setup

**MenuItemsPage.xaml**

```
    <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="425" Margin="75,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"
             ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryButtonList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource foodTypeTemplate}" >
    </ListBox>
```

In my MenuItemsPage I have the DataContext setup in code. Perhaps I should be setting this up in the xaml to keep my **cs** clean?

**MenuItemsPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MenuItemsPage : Page
    {
        public MenuItemsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();                   
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string tableName = e.Parameter as string;
            this.DataContext = new MenuPageVM(tableName);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: why would you send the button as a command parameter?

Comment: It's my way of seeing which button was clicked. Is that a bad way of doing things?

Comment: it does not make sense and the view model should not know anything about the UI, you do know that if you use `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` then you get the model itself as a parameter?

Comment: use x:Name and ElementName bindings to avoid relative bindings, which suck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` of a `DataTemplate` (and all its children, such as your `Button`) *is* the `ItemsSource` of the actual `ListBox`. If the command is defined within the `DataContext` of the *window*, then use either `ElementName` or `RelativeSource`:

```
<Window x:Name="MyWindow" ... >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="...">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

or

```
<Window ... >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="...">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: The first worked! I had to name my page and use ElementName to reference it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try referring the datacontext of the ListBox using "ElementName" and "DataContext.OnButtonClickedCommand"

```
<ListBox x:Name ="CategoryListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="425" Margin="75,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"
             ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryButtonList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource foodTypeTemplate}" >
    </ListBox>


<DataTemplate x:Key="foodTypeTemplate">
    <Button x:Name="button1" Width="100" Height="50" Content="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Name}" 
              Command="{Binding DataContext.OnButtonClickedCommand, ElementName = CategoryListBox}"                   
            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button1}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```